# Are there some modern ways to deploy programs via GPO without scripts in 2019?

Tags: installation, group-policy, windows-server, windows-server-2016, deployment

Scripts are good for sure but maybe we have something more *modern* to let's say Skype or Team Viewer on PCs on a domain using Windows server 2012 r2, 2016, 2019?

Comment: Not sure what server versions we are using, but our IT department flags certain programs in the MS Store as "allowed" and we can simply install ourselves.  Getting new stuff approved is a whole different story ...  Skype for Business is there and was part of default image, Teams is new default in image and available there as well for those with an older image.  Computers get imaged on replacement or when there are major changes (OS version, etc)

Comment: @ivanivan MS Store is a different story. But thanks for the idea! I meant more about classic way to install programs so not Stores, etc

Comment: You may always deploy a Windows MSI or MST package using Group Policy Software Installation, no script needed.